# Why C++ doesn't default construct return value when return statement is not specified?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to the C++ standard function not returning the value produce an undefined behaviour. It was resonable for C where we don't have constructors but this why this haven't fixed in C++11/14/17?

I think it is natural to default-construct return value if no return statement occur during execution. It will make code cleaner and safer without breaking compatibility with old C++ and C code.

Compare:

```
optional<int> foo() try {
   return some_complex_computation();
} catch (err1& e) {
   LOG << e;
   return none;
} catch (err2& e) {
   LOG << e;
   return none;
} catch (err3& e) {
   LOG << e;
   // oops, undefined behaviour
}
```

and just

```
optional<int> foo() try {
   return some_complex_computation();
} catch (err1& e) {
   LOG << e;
} catch (err2& e) {
   LOG << e;
} catch (err3& e) {
   LOG << e;
}
```

Comment: How hard is it to type `return {};` that you need a language feature?

Comment: Any decent compiler will warn about this, turn up the warning level and/or actually start reading the warnings.

Comment: Man, I really hate looking at someone else's code with long functions peppered with return statements :(

Comment: The language standard for C++ is developed openly. If you feel that this might enhance the langauge feel free to file a propsoal. Here are the guidelines: https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal

Comment: In your example, it returns a good value, or throws an exception.  That's a good model.  Just re-raise the exception. If you do neither, you WANT the compiler to reject the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning a default-constructed value might be better than undefined behavior, but it's worse than the current state of affairs, which is that most compilers warn when the closing brace of a non-void function is (or may be) reachable.

Catching errors at compile-time is always best, and the current rule gives compiler developers the flexibility to do that.  By adding default-return, you blur the line between good code and bad code.

I suggest you read Raymond Chen's blog posts where he discusses that correct code is not enough, you need to be able to tell on inspection that is IS correct.  And he's not the only one, other well-known experts say the same thing.

- Raymond Chen: [Cleaner, more elegant, and harder to recognize](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/14/352949.aspx)
- Raymond Chen: [Cleaner, more elegant, and wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/22/118161.aspx)
- Joel Spolsky: [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)

Comment: I could see some marginal value in having a `default return <expression>;` statement that would be useful in code that has many places that are error (or "no value") returns and only a small number of places that return data. But you definitely would want to require a specific statement to invoke it. Otherwise, an accidentally omitted `return` would often not be detected at compile time.